# Parsing error: Unexpected token (41:20) when I try to render the "Total" component outside of the map

Tags: reactjs, redux, styled-components

I am trying to render a simple component named " inside this component but it's giving an error:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token (41:20)
```

Here's the code:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { StyledCartItem, StyledDescription, StyledTitle, StyledPrice, StyledRemove, StyledMobile, StyledQuantity } from "./styles/CartItem.styled"
import { EmptyCart } from "./styles/EmptyCart.styled";
import { FaAngleUp, FaAngleDown } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Flex } from "./styles/Flex.styled";
import Total from "./Total";

const CartItem = () => {
    const {cartItems} = useSelector((state) => state.cart)

  return (
    <>
            {cartItems.length < 1 ? (
                <EmptyCart>
                    Your cart is empty
                </EmptyCart>
            ) : (
            cartItems.map((item, index) => (
                <Flex key={index}>
                    <div>
                    <StyledCartItem>
                        <StyledMobile>
                            <img src={item.img} alt="" />
                        </StyledMobile>
                        <StyledDescription>
                            <StyledTitle>{item.title}</StyledTitle>
                            <StyledPrice>{`$${item.price}`}</StyledPrice>
                            <StyledRemove>remove</StyledRemove>
                        </StyledDescription>
                    </StyledCartItem>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <StyledQuantity>
                        <FaAngleUp color={'#839192'} />
                            {item.amount}
                        <FaAngleDown color={'#839192'} />
                    </StyledQuantity>
                </div>
            </Flex>  
            ))
            <Total />
            )
            }      
    </>
  )
}

export default CartItem
```

When you hover over to the `<Total />` it says "Expression Expected".

I know I am missing something simple but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your component in the else condition of ternary operator has syntax issue. Please check if this works as per your requirement.

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
    StyledCartItem,
    StyledDescription,
    StyledTitle,
    StyledPrice,
    StyledRemove,
    StyledMobile,
    StyledQuantity,
} from "./styles/CartItem.styled";
import { EmptyCart } from "./styles/EmptyCart.styled";
import { FaAngleUp, FaAngleDown } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Flex } from "./styles/Flex.styled";
import Total from "./Total";

const CartItem = () => {
    const { cartItems } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

    return (
        <>
            {cartItems.length < 1 ? (
                <EmptyCart>Your cart is empty</EmptyCart>
            ) : (
                <>
                    {cartItems.map((item, index) => (
                        <>
                            <Flex key={index}>
                                <div>
                                    <StyledCartItem>
                                        <StyledMobile>
                                            <img src={item.img} alt="" />
                                        </StyledMobile>
                                        <StyledDescription>
                                            <StyledTitle>{item.title}</StyledTitle>
                                            <StyledPrice>{`$${item.price}`}</StyledPrice>
                                            <StyledRemove>remove</StyledRemove>
                                        </StyledDescription>
                                    </StyledCartItem>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <StyledQuantity>
                                        <FaAngleUp color={"#839192"} />
                                        {item.amount}
                                        <FaAngleDown color={"#839192"} />
                                    </StyledQuantity>
                                </div>
                            </Flex>
                            <Total />
                        </>
                    ))}
                </>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default CartItem;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do it like this:
`{cartItems.length < 1 ? (null) : (
            <div>
                <Total />
                <ClearCart />
            </div>
            )}
`